# Draw approximate curve using quadratic equation

Tags: python, numpy, algebra, quadratic, quadratic-curve

I have a graph that generates 4 curves and I need to draw an approximate graph using `ax2+bx+c` for a particular area.

So I have. Collection of data points `(x,y)....` up to `....1000`

My question:

```
1. is there any algo for selecting appropiate three point data point
```

**purpose** If I have three data point.I can determine a,b,c and get y point after placing x value using algebra equation

**Problem** The point which I am selecting I am getting c value is higher and if I place into ax2+bx+c than it gives me data out of range.

```
2.is there any algo which draw approximate line of existing quadratic equation
```

> 3.Another approach is: we have x and y points. we can subtract in y by 1% or 2% and get y value and draw the graph. In that case,what will be appropriate value for y value

The implementation language is Python using any available library.[image]